# Google play link with Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

I have tried to link play store with analytics using  [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2956981?hl=en) , but i am unable to create link between in given picture there is no apply button visible so that i can create it successfully.
[image: picture]
Please guide me how to do it correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In My case, I can find "Enable Link" beside "Cancel" button(first one).  Try to edit it and again try.

Comment: i tried. but unable to see apply button. but i noticed one thing in image that The google play app is linked with analytics views in this property. but when i tried to see in reports there is not report available. it is showing this message "This report requires that you link your apps with Google Play"